# Using exponential decay in tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

The doc for `tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss` mentions the possibility to give a `learning_rate_decay_fn`, e.g. `tf.train.exponential_decay`. However, for the suggested decay function I did not find out how to pass the additional arguments (`decay_steps`, `decay_rate` and `staircase`).

First attempt:

```
def my_decay(a, b):
tf.train.exponential_decay(a, b, decay_steps=5000, decay_rate=0.5,
                           staircase=True, name="LR_decay")


train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
    loss,
    global_step=global_counter,
    learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    learning_rate_decay_fn=my_decay
)
```

This results in a ValueError (Tried to convert 'values' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported). Probably due to the fact that the function is a python function and not a TensorFlow op.

Second attempt:

```
train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
    loss,
    global_step=global_counter,
    learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    learning_rate_decay_fn=tf.train.exponential_decay(decay_steps=5000, decay_rate=0.5,
                               staircase=True, name="LR_decay")
)
```

which complains about 2 missing positional arguments (as calling the function with missing parameters does not return a function but results in an attempt at evaluation).

Another attempt of adding the positional arguments to the `optimize_loss` function directly also failed (as the arguments are not passed down but seen as arguments to the function directly, which must fail.)

How can I pass the necessary arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to say `return tf.train.exponential_decay(...` in the definition of `my_decay`.

Comment: Ouch, that is embarassing. Thanks anyway.